# How can I cook a perfect deep-fried Mars bar?

Tags: frying, deep-frying, scottish-cuisine

I've seen on Internet the description of deep-fried Mars bar (dish originated at chip shops in Scotland), and I wonder how can I do it at home.

Comment: http://revision3.com/bites/friedmarsbar (not an answer because I don't have time ATM to write it up properly)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is to chill the Mars bar in a fridge for a few hours before cooking.

Prepare a batter mix (the kind you deep fry fish in) and get your oil heated to temperature. Here's a batter recipe I've used before:

> [Basic Fish Batter (Delia Smith Online)](http://www.deliaonline.com/how-to-cook/fish-and-shellfish/basic-fish-batter.html)

(You can't fault Delia!)

You can use sparkling water to introduce more bubbles into the batter which gives it a nice texture.

Remove the Mars Bar from the fridge and immediately coat in the batter and cook in the oil right away. Cook until the batter is golden and serve with a scoop of ice-cream.

You can also do this with Snickers bars. It's also worth trying with miniature Mars and Snickers bars.

As a Scotsman I must apologise for inflicting this culinary delight on the rest of the world :)

Comment: Fridge huh? Whenever I've done that they come out too soft and explosively hot and runny. When I do the freezer for a few hours, they come out perfectly.

Comment: Depends on what setting your fridge is at. Mine runs at just above freezing.

Comment: Can you edit in an example of an appropriate batter mix?

Comment: Delia has a deep fried mars bar recipe !!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The deep fried mars bar is the chippies answer to the chinese takeaway's doing Banana Fritters and the like, but the true Zenith of deep fried confectionary is the Deep Fried Snickers Icecream.

A twist on the mars bar is to get some really sour green eating apples and press slices into the sides of the marsbar before coating it with batter.

And whatever you do don't fall into the trap of a deep fried creme egg, those are evil!